# How to aim a check box in scripting when Checkbox got Text added (Livecycle Designer)

Tags: javascript, colors, aem, livecycle-designer

I want to get a colored edge around a checkbox in lifecycle with scripts (only want it if it's not filled out, but that's not the point). Now the checkbox got caption added, so if I do this:

```
this.border.edge.color.value = "200, 100, 50";
```

the Script will color the whole control (also the text and not only the checkbox). How can I aim the checkbox only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me to set the border around the checkbox itself to red. I added this code to the 'click' event:

```
this.ui.checkButton.border.edge.color.value="255,0,0";
```